# Reusing Persistence Context in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

i was just working on @EmbededId code, i want to do an auto increment before the entity is persisted, this is want to do without use of @GeneratedValue and an identity column,

below is the table with composite id,

```
create table TBL_EMPLOYEE_002(
    ID integer, 
    COUNTRY varchar(50),
    NAME varchar(50),
    constraint PK_EMP_00240 primary key(ID,COUNTRY)
)
```

this is the code for Entity mapping,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEE_002")
public class EmployeeEntitySix implements Serializable{

// contructor's

    @EmbeddedId    
    private EmployeeIdTwo id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String employeeName;

// getters and setter's

    @PrePersist
    public void incId(){
        EntityManager em = null;
        Query q = null;
       EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
        try{
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("forPractise");
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            q = em.createQuery("select max(e.id.employeeId) from EmployeeEntitySix e");
            List list = q.getResultList();
            Integer i = (list != null && list.size() > 0) ? Integer.valueOf(list.get(0).toString()) : 0;
            this.getId().setEmployeeId(++i);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("EXCETION WHILE INCREASING COUNTER...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(em != null && em.isOpen()){
                em.close();
            }
            if(getEmf() != null && getEmf().isOpen()){
                getEmf().close();
            }
        }


}
```

This is the composite id mapping,

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeIdTwo implements Serializable{


    @Column(name="ID") 
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Column(name="COUNTRY",length=50)
    private String empCountry;

// getters and setters

    }
```

this code is of my main method, this main method is in some other class,

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    EntityManager em = null;
    EntityTransaction tx = null;
    try{
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("forPractise");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        tx = em.getTransaction();            
        tx.begin();
    EmployeeEntitySix employee = new EmployeeEntitySix(new EmployeeIdTwo("ZIMBABWE"), "Henry Olanga");
    em.persist(employee);
....
}
```

Now the above code runs fine,
whenever i persist the entity "EmployeeEntitySix", the method annotated with @PerPersist runs, which will first fetch the max id, increments its, set it into the id in the embeded entity and persist the entity.

Now my question is,

I am creating EntityManagerFactory twice,
first in the main method,
second time in the @PrePersist method in entity EmployeeEntitySix. So whether i can use the first Entitymanagerfactory created in main method in the entity EmployeeEntitySix while pre-persist, or else whether i can reuse the entitymanager created in first time in main method in the @PrePersist method in entity.

Just for information, I am using plain java environment, I am not using a Java EE container.

Comment: You didn't show what getEMF() does, but if it is static it is probably not a good idea to close the EMF while in a persistence callback and the provider is using it

Comment: but my question is, how will i reuse the EmtityManager which i have created in main method, in @PrePersist method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate by default tries to persist all fields of an entity class or embedded id, including the field `emf`, but it does not know how to persist a field of the type `EntityManagerFactory`.

Of course it does not make sense to persist an `EntityManagerFactory`. You could mark the field as `@Transient` to prevent it from being persisted, but then you are just going to  face different problems.

The injection of an `EntityManagerFactory` with a `@PersistenceUnit` annotation only works on CDI Beans and EJBs in applications that run on a Java EE-compliant application server. As you are using a main method, I assume that your example is a simple JSE program.

Furthermore you should not access `EntityManager`s in lifecycle callback methods such as `@PrePersist`. A quote from the JPA Specification ([JSR 317: JavaTM Persistence API, Version 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf)):

*In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager
or Query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the
same persistence context. A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship
state of the entity on which it is invoked.*

I suggest that you keep the `EntityManagerFactory` out of your embedded id class and also get rid of the `incId`-Method. Instead you could execute the query to determine the new `employeeId` in your main method, before calling `persist`. This works fine as long as only one instance of the program works with the database. When there are multiple programs trying to insert new employees there could be race conditions where the two programs try to insert the same id.

In order to prevent this you can use a database sequence to generate the `employeeId`, with the annotations `@GeneratedValue` and `@SequenceGenerator`. You find more information about id generation here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Sequencing

Comment: i have edited my question, here i have moved the code of PrePersist to the Entity EmployeeEntitySix, my question was how can i reuse the EntityManager which is created in main method, in the PrePersist method of entity EmployeeEntitySix

Comment: The only way to do that I can think of is using a public static variable for the EntityManager, but I advise strongly against that, for a variety of reasons, one being the above-mentioned quote from the JPA specification.